# Github python script fatal: pathspec

Tags: python

I have made a github script. everything works fine. It adds, commits, and pushes. The only thing is i get and fatal: pathspec, but it still adds the file, commits, and pushes. Here is some code

```
  from subprocess import call

  add = raw_input('what file to add?:  ')
  call(["git", "add", add ])
     #fatal: pathspec   here. still adds file though.
  call(["git", "commit", "-m", add ])
      #still commits
  call(["git", "push", "origin", "master" ])
     #still pushes to origin master
```

I can deal with the error. It would just be nice not to have it. Should i use a different module? In the whole code i do have two if statements, but im not sure if that would bother nothing.

Comment: Have you checked out [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) yet?

Comment: ive not heard of that

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the gittle, [gittle in git hub](https://github.com/FriendCode/gittle). It makes git more easy.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: i did    pip install gitpython    no module named gitpython?

Comment: import gittle      no module named funky?